# Pasting three columns of unequal length

Tags: r

Let's say that I have the following data frame and want to past together the three columns into a fourth column

```
df = data.frame(one=c("honda","ford","kia","bmw"),
                two=c("subaru","","","lexus"),
                three=c("","","","ford"))
```

I can use paste to combine all three.

```
df$label = paste(df$one, df$two, df$three, sep=" - ")
df
```

Unfortunately, this causes the following because of the 'empty' values in the data frame.

```
> df
    one    two three              label
1 honda subaru        honda - subaru - 
2  ford                      ford -  - 
3   kia                       kia -  - 
4   bmw  lexus  ford bmw - lexus - ford
```

I could just clean up the label column and remove the lagging dashes, but is there a way to do this in paste() so that I end up with no extra dashes when there isn't a value in two or three.

Should look like:

```
> df
    one    two three              label
1 honda subaru            honda - subaru
2  ford                         ford
3   kia                          kia
4   bmw  lexus  ford    bmw - lexus - ford
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
> df$label <- apply(df, 1, function(x) paste(x[x!=''], collapse=' - '))
> df
    one    two three              label
1 honda subaru           honda - subaru
2  ford                            ford
3   kia                             kia
4   bmw  lexus  ford bmw - lexus - ford
```